# Using PMML to use python-trained model in JAVA

Tags: java, python-3.x, scikit-learn, grid-search, pmml

I'm training an MLP estimator using GridSearchCV in python and want to export it to JAVA using pmml.
What is the best way to do it?
I tried:

```
estimator = grid.best_estimator
pipeline = PMMLPipeline([("best_estimator", estimator)])
pmml_pipeline = sklearn2pmml(pipeline, "pipeline")
pickle.dump(pmml_pipeline, open(pipeline_name, "wb") )
```

and get the error:

```
    WARNING: Attribute 'sklearn2pmml.pipeline.PMMLPipeline.target_fields' is not set. Assuming y as the name of the target field
Mar 27, 2018 3:30:00 PM sklearn2pmml.pipeline.PMMLPipeline initFeatures
    raise RuntimeError("The JPMML-SkLearn conversion application has failed. The Java executable should have printed more information about the failure into its standard output and/or standard error streams")
RuntimeError: The JPMML-SkLearn conversion application has failed. The Java executable should have printed more information about the failure into its standard output and/or standard error streams
WARNING: Attribute 'sklearn2pmml.pipeline.PMMLPipeline.active_fields' is not set. Assuming [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12, x13, x14, x15, x16, x17, x18, x19, x20, x21, x22, x23, x24, x25, x26, x27, x28, x29, x30, x31, x32, x33, x34, x35, x36, x37, x38, x39, x40, x41, x42, x43, x44, x45, x46, x47, x48, x49, x50] as the names of active fields
Mar 27, 2018 3:30:00 PM org.jpmml.sklearn.Main run
INFO: Converted in 121 ms.
Mar 27, 2018 3:30:00 PM org.jpmml.sklearn.Main run
INFO: Marshalling PMML..
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext
    at org.jpmml.model.JAXBUtil.getContext(JAXBUtil.java:126)
    at org.jpmml.model.MetroJAXBUtil.marshalPMML(MetroJAXBUtil.java:25)
    at org.jpmml.sklearn.Main.run(Main.java:159)
    at org.jpmml.sklearn.Main.main(Main.java:94)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: First, sklearn2pmml command doesnt return anything. So assigning it to `pmml_pipeline` is wrong. Second this error is due to your java version. Which version of java do you have? Is it 9?

Comment: If its java 9, then you are experiencing a [known issue](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml/issues/80). You need to work with java 8 or 7 or else change the sklearn2pmml library module yourself to add the required command.

Comment: Since sklearn2pmml is just a wrapper over the actual java program, you can alternatively use the java command yourself to convert a pickle file to pmml. See https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sklearn

Comment: @VivekKumar 1. So how should I save/pickle to object from sklearn2pmml? 
2. Re java version: I changed the version in the terminal to 8 but when I'm checking the version python uses, it is 9.. How can I set the java version python is using?
Thanks!